# Как при нажатии вытянуть кнопку только снизу? Не сверху

Tags: android, button

Я использую вот этот код:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams();

                int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 70, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    layoutParams.height = height;
                    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    layoutParams.height = height;
                    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Но этот код вытягивает кнопку сверху и снизу. А мне нужно только снизу вытянуть, как на фото. Как это сделать? Получается мне нужен -Y[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: gravity в контейнере выставьте на top, будет вытягиваться вниз. Внутри кнопки то же самое, чтобы Сб 24 не меняло свою позицию.

Comment: Спасибо! Я смог сделать, но есть проблемка. Текст внутри кнопок уходит на верхний левый угол, а мне нужно чтобы текст был по центру сверху. Как это сделать?

Comment: все та же gravity, у кнопки, по умолчанию top|left, вам нужно top|center_horizontal